# Module update with composer, updates module but not really

Tags: 8, composer

I am updating modules on my drupal site and I am using the composer like this:

```
composer require 'drupal/module'
```

The output I get from composer looks like everything is working fine but when I go to the update page of the modules nothing seems to change. The output from composer looks like this:

[image]

This is an occurence on every module I have.

composer.json :

```
{
"name": "drupal/legacy-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^8.8",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
    "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.1",
    "drupal/fontawesome_menu_icons": "^1.9",
    "drupal/geofield": "^1.31",
    "drupal/imce": "^2.4",
    "drupal/memcache": "^2.3",
    "drupal/r4032login": "^2.1",
    "drupal/token": "^1.9",
    "drupal/views_base_url": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.13",
    "drupal/weight": "^3.3"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": ["homepage", "support"],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",

            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the files are correct?

Comment: Do you mean the info file of the module? If that yes. It has the old version.

Comment: And you’ve checked the obvious things like you’re running composer commands in the correct folder etc? If so your composer is broken, try reinstalling it

Comment: `composer require` and `composer update` only download files, you still need to check for database updates `drush updb` and a cache clear `drush cr` afterwards

Comment: @Clive yes I have checked that I am running composer commands in the correct folder. That will be drupal's root right?

Comment: @Hundri Yes I run both drush updb and drush cr after the composer commands

Comment: @pierostz can you post your composer.json file code? Are you sure you're looking with your browser at the correct site and not at a clone that doesn't have the updated module?

Comment: @NoSssweat I have added the composer.json file. I think Clive is right. I should remove composer and re-add it...but how do I do that?

Comment: Docker? Maybe a syncing issue? Restart server, maybe a caching issue.

Comment: There is some detail missing here. Composer is updating, I have never seen it download files and _not_ change. The included pic and json is weird, you requested 2.3, you got 2.3.0 of memcache module, reflected in composer.json. What did not download?

Comment: Also if you are updating modules, you should `composer update drupal/module`, not require again.

Comment: You said " I go to the update page of the modules nothing seems to change. " which page is the update page? And what do you expect to see change?